# MS chart candlestick How to set tail colors

Tags: c#, charts, bar-chart, mschart, candlestick-chart

I am currently developing a candlestick chart with mschart in visual C#.
I have now created two charts and created the charts as follows

Question 1. View the Candlestick Chart at the top. I would like to apply the tail color of each rod as red or blue.

Question 2. View the bar chart at the bottom. I would like to apply Red or Blue color to this chart. I want to apply the same color to the top of the Candlestick chart. How can I do it ?

[source]

```
DataTable table_ChartData = new DataTable();
table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Id");
table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Open");
table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Close");
table_ChartData.Columns.Add("High");
table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Low");
table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Day");
dataGridView1.DataSource = table_ChartData;  

chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = max;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = min;

chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.WordWrap;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;


chart1.Series["Candle"].XValueMember = "Day";            
chart1.Series["Candle"].YValueMembers = "High,Low,Open,Close,Volume";
chart1.Series["Candle"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date;
chart1.Series["Candle"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Blue,PriceUpColor=Red";
chart1.Series["Candle"]["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Triangle";
chart1.Series["Candle"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
chart1.DataSource = table_ChartData;
chart1.DataBind();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = v_max + (v_max / 10);
chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = v_min / 2;

chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.WordWrap;
chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;


chart2.Series["Bar"].XValueMember = "Day";
chart2.Series["Bar"].YValueMembers = "Volume";
chart2.Series["Bar"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date;
chart2.Series["Bar"].YValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Int32;
chart2.DataSource = table_ChartData;
chart2.DataBind();
```

[image]

Comment: Q1: Please define 'tailcolor' Candlestick has hi,lo,open&close values -  Q2 You can set the colors of each datapoint. for loop over the points after binding. If the two charts have corresponding points you can test the top values and set the colors in the bottom. What is the condition?

Answer (score 5):

In a [Candlestick Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456671.aspx) there are `CustomProperties` to automatiaclly set the colors of the boxes, depending on the trend:

```
someSeries.SetCustomProperty("PriceUpColor", "Green");   
someSeries.SetCustomProperty("PriceDownColor", "Red");
```

Unfortunately there is no way to set the colors of the lines that connect the high- and low-values.

But, unless you have messed with other Custom attributes and if the x-values are meaningful, you can easily draw those lines, and by drawing the top and the bottom part separately you can also use different colors.

Here is an example:

```
private void chart6_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea ca = chart6.ChartAreas[0];
    Series s = chart6.Series[0];
    Pen hiPen = Pens.Green;
    Pen loPen = Pens.Red;

    if (e.ChartElement == s)
    foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points)
    {
        float x       = (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue);
        float y_hi    = (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]);
        float y_low   = (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[1]);
        float y_open  = (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[2]);
        float y_close = (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[3]);

        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(hiPen, x, y_low, x, Math.Min(y_close, y_open));
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(loPen, x, y_hi,  x, Math.Max(y_close, y_open));
    }
}
```

To set Colors for the 2nd Chart's points you need to loop over the points as there Colors [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027058/binding-list-of-lists-to-chart-control/33082008?s=6|0.0956#33082008) be set in binding.

The code is simple:

```
void SetColors(Series candles, Series columns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candles.Points.Count; i++)
    {
        DataPoint dp = candles.Points[i];
        columns.Points[i].Color =
            dp.YValues[2] > dp.YValues[3] ? Color.Red :  Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Call it after binding!

Result:

[image]

Note that to avoid seeing the original lines shine through we set the `BorderWidth` to 0:

```
someSeries.BorderWidth = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
priceSerie.Points[index].Color = Color.Blue;
// priceSerie.Points[index].BorderColor = Color.Magenta;
```